# Word Mail-Merge not showing elapsed seconds correctly

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

I'm doing a mail-merge in Word 2010 with an Excel 2010 file as the data source. Everything is working fine except a field where 'elapsed time' is being calculated.

In Excel, the field appears correctly: 193 seconds is showing as 00:03:13 -- for three minutes, thirteen seconds.

When I insert the field in Word it shows up as a time of day: 12:03:05 AM

Is there a MERGEFIELD code that formats this correctly in Word? I haven't been able to find one yet. If there is a work-around, I'd be interested in hearing that as well.

Comment: You could take the computed values in Excel and convert them into text (the text version of the result living in another column). Merging the converted text values in Word will probably give you the same result within the Mail Merge.

Comment: Yes, I tried to format the field as a Number, General, Text, etc. Nothing seemed to work. That's why I was looking for some sort of code that would format it correctly.

Comment: @bibadiak, your answer worked perfectly! How do I award you the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a date format switch to your field as follows:

```
{ MERGEFIELD mydate \@mm:ss }
```